# Trying to write some T-SQL to iterate through the DB tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 on dev, and SQL Azure for test and live.

I wish to write a little procedure to reset the identity seeds since SQL Azure does not support DBCC.

I have some workaround code which works, but I do not want to write it out for each table, so was trying to write a routine that iterates through the DB tables.

Tables:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

Code:

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where Id>150000
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE_NAME] ON
GO 
INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME](Id) VALUES(150000)
GO 
delete from TABLE_NAME where Id=150000
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE_NAME] OFF
GO
```

I guess I need to wrap this in a loop. Sorry my T-SQL is not that strong, hence the request for help.

Also it would be helpful to omit all tables with `TABLE_NAME` starting with `aspnet_` and use only `TABLE_TYPE = "BASE TABLE"`

Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless somebody else knows a trick that I don't, you're probably stuck using dynamic SQL and iterating through a list of table names using either a cursor or a temporary table. The cursor approach would look something like this:

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(257);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

declare TableCursor cursor read_only for
select 
    TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME 
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
where 
    TABLE_NAME not like 'aspnet\_%' escape '\' and
    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';

open TableCursor;
fetch next from TableCursor into @TableName;

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'select top 1 * from ' + @TableName;
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
    fetch next from TableCursor into @TableName;
end

close TableCursor;
deallocate TableCursor;
```

You can read more about cursors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx). Alternatively, you could do it with an in-memory table like this:

```
declare @Tables table (RowId int identity(1, 1), TableName nvarchar(257));
declare @TableName nvarchar(257);
declare @Index int;
declare @TableCount int;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

insert into @Tables (TableName)
select 
    TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME 
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
where 
    TABLE_NAME not like 'aspnet\_%' escape '\' and
    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';

set @TableCount = @@rowcount;
set @Index = 1

while @Index <= @TableCount
begin
    select @TableName = TableName from @Tables where RowId = @Index;
    set @sql = 'select top 1 * from ' + @TableName;
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
    set @Index = @Index + 1;
end
```

In the interest of brevity, my examples use a much simpler SQL statement than yours—I'm just selecting one record from each table—but this ought to be enough to illustrate how you can get this done.